# Kernel of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix with diagonal blocks zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, block-matrices

We have a $2 \times 2$ block matrix M, in which the diagonal blocks are $0$. The sizes of the upper rigt block is $N_B \times N_A$ and the size of the lower left block is $N_A \times N_B$, where we know $N_B \geq N_A$. We also know that rank(M) = $2 N_A$.

An example of such matrix M with $N_A = 2$ and $N_B = 3$ is $ \begin{pmatrix}
0& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0& 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1& 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5& 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} .$

QUESTION: We need to show that for every vector $v \in$ ker($M$), it holds that the first $N_A$ elements of $v$ are $0$ (or equivalently we need to show that $v \in \{0\}^{N_A} \times R^{N_B}.$.) (For the above example, vector $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0 \\
1\\
1 \\
5\\
\end{pmatrix}$ does have the first $N_A = 2$ elements equal to $0$ and the vector $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
2 \\
1\\
1 \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$doesn't. )

I tried to prove it, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

$M$ maps $V = R ^{N_A + N_B}$ to $V$. We define $A = R^{N_A} \times \{0\}^{N_B}$ and $B = \{0\}^{N_A} \times R^{N_B}$, which means $V = A \bigoplus B , dim(A) = N_A $ and $dim(B) = N_B.$
We can define two maps $$f: A \to B, f(x) = Mx$$ and $$g: B \to A, g(x) = Mx.$$
Since $dim(B) = N_B \geq dim(A) = N_A$ and $g$ is a linear map, we know $dim(ker(g))\geq N_B - N_A$.

Since $rank(M) = 2_$, we know $dim(ker(M)) = N_B - N_A$.

We see that $ker(g) \subseteq ker(M)$, since for every $v \in B \subseteq V$ it holds $v \in ker(g) \implies g(v) = 0 \implies Mv = 0 $$\implies v \in ker(M)$.

Since $ker(g) \subseteq ker(M)$ and $dim(ker(g)) \geq dim(ker(M))$, it follows that $ker(g) = ker(M)$. Therefore for every vector $v \in$ ker(M), it holds that the first $N_A$ elements of $v$ are $0$ (otherwise $v$ would not be in $B$).

Comment: Hint : what is the maximal rank of the last $N_B$ columns of $M$ ? Then, since you require rank$(M)=2N_A$ what is the minimal rank that the first $N_A$ columns must have ? This should lead directly to the conclusion that the first $N_A$ elements of  $v$ must vanish.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Does the term vanish mean that they must be equal to 0? I see that the first $N_A$ columns of M must have rank $N_A$, but could you explain why does it imply that the first $N_A$ elements of every $v \in ker(M)$ must be equal to 0?

Comment: The first $N_A$ columns must have rank $N_A$. In other words, they are linearly independent. The first $N_A$ components of $v$ are nothing else than the coefficients of a linear combination of those columns. Hence they must be zero when the resulting linear combination is supposed to be zero.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. Do you maybe know if my proof was also correct?

Comment: Yes. Your proof looks correct.